# How to set data in firebase database from array?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

Can you help me to solve this problem?

```
export class SomePage {
reg = [{apple: 201, ball: 21, cat: 12}, {apple: 202, ball: 65, cat: 15}];

constructor() {
  firebase.database().ref('app/test').set({
    // i want to set all ***cat*** values here like:
    // key1: 12
    // key2: 15
})
```

.

Tried to extract `cat` values with this method:

```
let keys = this.reg.map(a => a.cat);
console.log(keys);  // <unavailable>
```

Comment: You can extract the cat values using filter. ```var catValues = reg.filter(function(item){ console.log(item['cat'])});```

Comment: Will it extract array data for the `catValues` variable? It will just show console log like `this.reg.forEach((snap) => {console.log(snap.cat)});`

Comment: `this.reg.map(a => a.cat);` will return an array of `cat` values from the reg array. What kind of output do you require?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have your reg array of objects.
2. Initialize the resultObject
3. Create a counter to increment the key of resultObject
4. Filter all cat values from reg array and set it to resultObject.
5. Update it in your firebase db.

---

```
//1
var reg = [{apple: 201, ball: 21, cat: 12}, {apple: 202, ball: 65, cat: 15}];
//2        
var resultObject = {};
//3
var count = 0;
//4
reg.filter(function(elem){ resultObject['key'+ ++count] = elem.cat});
//5
constructor() {
  firebase.database().ref('app/test').set(resultObject);
}
```

Comment: `first argument contains undefined in property 'app.test.undefined.0'` It hasn't set properly to call.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution:

```
this.reg.map(a => { 
  let first = a.ball; // or add any key
  let addORupdate = {};
  addORupdate[first]  = a.cat;  // expected value from array
  firebase.database().ref('app/test').update(addORupdate);
  // this will add 21:12 and 65:15 under the parent "test"
});
```